# PHP gethostbyname() работает очень медленно

Tags: php, сеть

Есть многопоточный скрипт, который обрабатывает данные, в том числе получает адрес указанного домена. И в этом месте сильно тормозит - gethostbyname() занимает кучу времени. Как можно увеличить скорость работы скрипта? Спасибо.

Comment: Обычно никак. dns должна на каждый ваш запрос опросить несколько серверов (если данных нет в кеше). Если кеша DNS недостаточно можно кешировать в самом скрипте ответы.

Comment: Я понял, то есть, грубо говоря все упирается в скорость ответа от сервера, который знает какой записи какой адрес соответствует?

Comment: И как правильно кешировать? Я ничего умнее сохранения в ассоциативный массив придумать не могу.

Comment: В общем да. А учитывая, что запросы могут идти рекурсивно, то может идти опрос нескольких серверов, сначала ".", потом "ru.", за ним "expamlpe.ru." ну и если есть субдомены то опять отдельные запросы. Если сам DNS сервер с которым работает машина, на которой ваш скрипт не на ней самой, то еще плюс время его ответа

Comment: Собственно ничего умнее ассоциативного массива и нет :) Не держать же для таких вещей memcached.

Comment: только при кешировании желателен механизм устаревания записей. скажем если ответ получен больше часа назад то его выбрасывать и перезапрашивать DNS

Comment: @Mike, понял, спасибо за подсказку!